# Textblock* over a figure after mouse command

Tags: beamer

I have started with beamer environment some days ago and some doubts are emerging. My question concerns about textblock over a figure. I would like to put a textblock over a figure after click mouse. Please, see below my first attemp to make it. Unfortunately, the figure and the textblock appear together.

Thanks in advance!

```
\begin{frame}

\frametitle{\large{Infrastructure du r\'eseau de distribution \'electrique \`a venir}}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim=0cm 0 0 1.3cm, width=1\textwidth]{Modern_power_grid.pdf}
\end{figure}

\begin{textblock*}{64mm}(32mm,0.31\textheight)
\begin{exampleblock}{}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Evolution}: \text{\color{red} \textbf{Passive}} $\Rightarrow$ \text{\color{blue} \textbf{Active}}     \item Plus complexe (flux bidirectionnel)
  \end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{textblock*}

\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **overlay** specifications; in the example code below I used `\only` (a `\pause` command after the `figure` environment would've been also enough) please refer to the `beamer` manual (Section **9 Creating Overlays**) to see all the options available. Since I don't have your actual image I changed a little some of the original settings just for the example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{textpos}

\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\large}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Infrastructure du r\'eseau de distribution \'electrique \`a venir}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=5cm,width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\only<2>{%
\begin{textblock*}{64mm}(32mm,-30mm)
\begin{exampleblock}{}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Evolution}: \text{\color{red} \textbf{Passive}} $\Rightarrow$ \text{\color{blue} \textbf{Active}}     \item Plus complexe (flux bidirectionnel)
  \end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{textblock*}%
}

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]